# How to write a function that transforms a function and returns the transformed function?

Tags: python, function, decorator

I want to perform some transformation on a function and return a new function.
Say for example I want a function `translate_arg_of_func(func)` such that

```
new_func=translate_arg_of_func(func)
new_func(4)
```

returns `func(4+1)`. How would I do this in python?

(I don't want `translate_arg_of_func` to have to be fed the arguments that are given to `func`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/), and can be written like this:

```
def translate_arg_of_func(func):
    def wrapper(arg):
        return func(arg + 1)
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 2):

You basically talk about decorating a function:

```
def translate_arg_of_func(fun):
    def new_fun(arg):
        return fun(arg + 1)
    return new_fun
```

Now you can decorate your function using:

```
new_func=translate_arg_of_func(func)
```

Or even decorate the function directly by using `@`:

```
@translate_arg_of_func
def func(arg):
    print(arg)
```

Answer (score 1):

It called decorator pattern, and welcome to the decorator world.

for example

```py
def add_more_1(func):
    def _mutate_func(*args):
        new_arg = args[0]+1
        return func(new_arg)
    return _mutate_func

def double(x):
    return x*2
print(double(2))

@add_more_1
def double_mutate(x):
    return x*2

print(double_mutate(2))
```